# Run Script on AWS @reboot?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm currently trying to run script that will run in the background when my AWS instance boots for the duration of the instance life.  I'm testing it with a simple script to see if it works, before I test with my more complicated one:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [true]; do
    sleep 1
    echo "Hello World" >> "tempStorage.json"
done
```

And my `sudo crontab -l` returns:

```
# All the comment stuff
@reboot sh /home/ubuntu/test/testScript/test.sh
```

Which is the path to the script.  I've also obviously run `chmod +x test.sh` to make sure its an executable.

The problem is when I stop and then start the AWS instance there's nothing in the `tempStorage.json` file.  I've checked other threads and they all suggest this is what I should be doing, so I'm very confused and advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark B mentioned, the issue is the execution directory of the cron script. There are two solutions then.

A) Change the path to file as Mark B recommended so the script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [true]; do
    sleep 1
    echo "Hello World" >> "/home/ubuntu/test/testScript/tempStorage.json"
done
```

B) Change the directory of the cron execution and keep the script as it was.  This works better if you need to put the script in any directory.  It would look like this for the crontab:

```
# All the comment stuff
@reboot cd /home/ubuntu/test/testScript && sh test.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine. I think the issue is that you aren't giving the full path to the `tempSTorage.json` file within your script. So it is being written to in a different folder than the one you are looking in, specifically whatever folder cron starts processes in by default. Try changing it to something like `/tmp/tempSTorage.json` and then rebooting the server again.

Note that if you are wanting something that starts on boot and runs forever, this probably isn't the best method. In that case I would look into running your process as a service.

Comment: You were totally right.  Good call, for some reason I thought it would execute in the path it found the script, but I see that I was wrong.  Probably going to cd and then run script and see if that works.

Comment: In response to your edit you're probably right about using it as a service, and I'll look into that, but at least the crontab question is now solved.

Comment: You could also put the `cd` command as the first step in the script, instead of in the crontab.

Comment: Yep and I mentioned that in the self-answer to this question.

Comment: No you don't mention that actually. I'm saying instead of putting the `cd` command in the crontab (as you mentioned in #2), you could put  `cd /home/ubuntu/test/testScript` inside the bash script. You could even get fancy and put something like `cd \`$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$BASH_SOURCE")")\`` so that it always changes to whatever directory the script happens to be in.